# Angular: How to make a time signal in

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to make a traffic light that from 0 to 10 minutes is green from 10 to 20 yellow and from 20 to 30 red, time is by service

So far this is my code

This is the component

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  TiempoService
} from "app/servicios/tiempo.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tiemposervice: TiempoService;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {


  }


}
```

This is the HTML

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <span>Tiempo transcurrido</span>
    <h5>{{tiempoTranscurrido | date:'mm:ss'}}</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the service

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import Rx from 'Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TiempoService {

  tiempoTranscurrido: number;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  tiempoTotal() {
    Rx.Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(segundos => {
      this.tiempoTranscurrido = segundos * 1000;
    })
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you need something like this:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LightService {
  getLight(interval): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.interval(interval)
      .timeInterval()
      .map(time => {
        if(time.value % 3 === 2) {
          return 'green';
        } else if(time.value % 3 === 0) {
          return 'yellow';
        } else if (time.value % 3 === 1) {
          return 'red';
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LightService } from './light.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ LightService ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  light: string = "green";

  constructor(private lightService: LightService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lightService
      .getLight(10000) // 10 seconds interval
      .subscribe(light => this.light = light);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<h1>
  {{ light }}
</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="light === 'green'" class="green"></li>
  <li *ngIf="light === 'yellow'" class="yellow"></li>
  <li *ngIf="light === 'red'" class="red"></li>
</ul>
```

Styles:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you need to show lights only once add take operator:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LightService {
  getLight(interval): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.interval(interval)
      .timeInterval()
      .map(time => {
        if(time.value % 3 === 2) {
          return 'green';
        } else if(time.value % 3 === 0) {
          return 'yellow';
        } else if (time.value % 3 === 1) {
          return 'red';
        }
      })
      .take(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: If it works, but in the end I want it to turn red, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Add `.take(2)` after `map` in `LightService`.